# How to read Python socket recv

Tags: python, sockets

I'm attempting to send an HTTP Request to a website and read the data it returns. The first website I tried worked successfully. It returned about 4 packets of data and then returned a 0 packet which the script caught and terminated.

However, attempting to load http://www.google.com/ does not work this way. Instead, it returns  about 10 packets of the same length, a final smaller packet, and then proceeds to time out. Is it normal for this to happen? Does it all just depend on what server the host is using?

If anyone could recommend an alternative way to reading with socket.recv() that would take into account that a final null packet is not always sent, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
    try:
        data = s.recv(4096)

        while True:
            more = s.recv(4096)
            print len(more)
            if not more:
                break
            else:
                data += more
    except socket.timeout:
        errMsg = "Connection timed-out while connecting to %s. Request headers were as     follows: %s", (parsedUrl.netloc, rHeader.headerContent)
        self.logger.exception(errMsg)
        raise Exception
```

Comment: Can you edit your question with the code above to see your request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For HTTP, use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) rather than writing your own.

```
> ipython

In [1]: import requests

In [2]: r = requests.get('http://www.google.com')

In [3]: r.status_code
Out[3]: 200

In [4]: r.text[:80]
Out[4]: u'<!doctype html><html itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">'

In [5]: len(r.text)
Out[5]: 10969
```

Comment: I wasted my time using sockets till somebody pointed me here.

Answer (score 3):

TCP does not give you "packets", but sequential *bytes* sent from the other side. **It is a stream**. `recv()` gives you chunks of that stream that are currently available. You stitch them back together and *parse* the stream content.

[HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP) is rather involved protocol to work out by hand, so you probably want to start with some existing library like [httplib](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html) instead.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not looking for alternatives. I would like to fix the problem at hand with sockets.

Comment: Then read those HTTP RFCs, figure out how to parse headers, compute response body length, handle different encodings, manage persistent connections, etc. etc. It's not easy but has been done on several occasions.

Comment: I understand this. One of my problems was I can't quite grasp how to grab the content-length and use that to grab the rest of the content.

Comment: Parse the response `Content-Length` header, figure out what's already in your buffer, read what's left (modulo multi-chunk encoding, which is a pain).

Comment: What would be the best way to figure out how many bytes I've already collected?

Comment: You have some data read so far, that includes the status line, response header (maybe only a part of it), and maybe a part of the body. Find double `\r\n` in your buffer - that'd be the end of the header, rest is the (partial) content. Seriously, take a look at those RFCs :)

Answer (score 2):

It could be that Google uses [Keep-Alive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection) to keep the socket open in order to serve a further request. This would require parsing of the header and reading the exact number of bytes.

Depending  on which version of HTTP you use, you have to add `Connection: Keep-Alive` to your headers or not. (This might be the simplest solution: just use HTTP/1.0 instead of 1.1.)

If you use that feature nevertheless, you would have to receive your first chunk of data and

1. parse if there is a `'\r\nContent-Length: '` inside, and if so, take the bytes between that and the next `'\r\n'` and convert them to a number. That is your size.
2. Have a look if you have a `'\r\n\r\n'` in your data. If so, that is the end of your header. From here, you must read the exact number of bytes mentionned above.

Example:

```
import socket
s = socket.create_connection(('www.google.com', 80))
s.send("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n")
x = s.recv(10000)
poscl = x.lower().find('\r\ncontent-length: ')
poseoh = x.find('\r\n\r\n')
if poscl < poseoh and poscl >= 0 and poseoh >= 0:
    # found CL header
    poseocl = x.find('\r\n',poscl+17)
    cl = int(x[poscl+17:poseocl])
    realdata = x[poseoh+4:]
```

Now, you have the content length in `cl` and the (start of the) payload data in `realdata`. The number of bytes missing of this request is `missing = cl - len(realdata)`. If it is `0`, you've got everything; if not, do `s.read(missing)` and recalculate `missing` until it is 0.

The code above is a simppe start of the job to be done; there are some places where you might need to `recv()` further before you can proceed.

This is quite compliated. By far easier ways would be

1. to use HTTP 1.1's `Connection: close` header in the request,
2. to use HTTP 1.0,
3. to use one of the libraries crafted for this task and not to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Think a step further: `len()` of what would y ou use? That makes no sense... No, you must parse the answer and act appropriately. I'll update the answer.